# How to use Variables in setState in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use a variable in the setState function in a JSX file for React.

How would I restructure this code:

```
var name = e.target.name;
if(name == "title"){
    this.setState({ title: e.target.value});
}
else if(name == "date"){
    this.setState({ date: e.target.value});
}
else if(name == "amount"){
    this.setState({ amount: e.target.value});
}
```

Into something like this (so I don't repeat myself)?

```
var name = e.target.name;
this.setState({ name: e.target.value});
```

The above syntax just sets the state of "name" and not the value of the "name" variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy:

```
var newState = {};
newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
this.setState(newState);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var update = {};
update[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
this.setState(update);
```

If you're using an ES6 transpliler that supports computed property names (like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#enhanced-object-literals)), you can do:

```
this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
```